# Turtle wax headlight restorer kit not drying

Tags: headlight, restoration

Is used the Turtle wax headlight restorer kit to remove the yellowish haze from my headlights.
I followed the instructions and as the last steps I applied the "basecoat" wipe, after a few minutes it dried and then I applied the "sealing wipe".
According to instructions it should take 24 hours to dry but that time passed and it is still wet.

Should I just wait some more? Or wipe it off?
I am concerned that it will not give a smooth surface.

(note there are several versions of this product, the one I used had a clarifying compound bottle, spray lubricant bottle, two sandpaper pads and two soaked wipes: the basecoat wipe and a lens sealing wipe)

Comment: Is it cold in your part of the world? If so, it might explain why it's still wet. Although I have no idea what you're supposed to "seal" with the sealing wipe. But that's not important at this particular moment. Give it another 24 hours or else take a hair dryer to it.

Comment: It is warm, about 30 degrees (Celsius) during daytime, 20 at night, humidity is around 50 %. No rains that day.

Comment: Abut the sealing wipe, it is a wipe labeled "lens sealing wipe". It should be applied after the other wipe. Here is an image: https://i.cdn.nrholding.net/16247075/450/450/

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I thought it was some sort of clearcoat applicator or something. At any rate, those conditions are pretty good for letting things dry out. I don't know, best is to either mail someone at Turtle Wax and hope they respond or put a heater at a reasonable distance from the lamp and see what happens. Worst case is you'll have to sand them a bit again.

Comment: I have used the same product my only noticeable difference after it dried is, it marked on the lens. before i wiped with the basecoat and lens seal, it shows a clear lens. can I sand it again?

Comment: Had same problem with the Holts kit ! It works good but the aerosol spray on sealer never dries !! Had to just wipe off eventually as headlights looked like a rave for bugs etc !!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'd be very concerned about the "sealing wipe" not drying. As Juann pointed out, your conditions seem to be good for drying, so either it's as dry as it'll get or else something's interfering with it drying.

For future reference, you can use ordinary car wax after wet-sanding with 2000-grit sandpaper. The car wax MUST be a "100% carnauba" paste wax, containing NO silicone... and a container of it will outlast your car, and your next car, and your next; it takes VERY LITTLE wax to finish out a headlight.

Good examples of suitable ordinary wax are Johnson's Paste Wax, Butcher's Bowling Alley Wax, and some types of the ubiquitous Turtle wax. Do check the label - it should someplace read either "no silicone" or "100% carnauba".